# Optimize a large MySQL query (caching or something similar?)

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I'm not used to working with such big objects (*hehe*). I've got a query that runs through all of my subdomains from a mysql query:

```
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( 
  "SELECT blog_id,path FROM {$wpdb->blogs} 
  WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} 
  AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}' 
  AND spam = '0' 
  AND deleted = '0' 
  AND archived = '0' 
  order by blog_id", ARRAY_A
);
```

Then I run a foreach over them to get some data (blog name, specifically)

```
foreach( $blogs as $blog ) : 
    switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );
    if(strpos(strtolower($blog_details->blogname), strtolower($_GET['squery'])) !== false){
    //Show the site's title and link to the site
}
endforeach;
```

I'm doing this because I need users to be able to search for a site by it's NAME which isn't available in the `$wpdb->blogs` table. the URL is, but the url may be smsalem" but a user would be searching for something like "Service Master" or even just "Service".

I upped my memory limit to 256mb (is that too high? Or can I go higher?) because I was getting a memory exhausted error.

Now it completes just fine, and I echoed the memory usage and got **201043248**, 201mb. My initial `$blogs` array has ~1,400 items in it.

This "works" but I'm afraid that 201mb is very high everytime someone uses that page (we have a dedicated server), I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize this a bit or if these numbers are low enough to not worry about (we're probably looking at 5k+ sites in the next year or two)

Comment: Try reading about joins/subqueries. Combine that with HAVING condition in your where block and you get results directly from the database. You should use paging instead of fetching all the results at once

Comment: i would create a table of all the sites, once, then maintain it.

Comment: @Dagon - So you're saying to create a table (using a similar query to the above) that contains the site id's AND all the data I need, and then maintain then, and run my queries off that that, so I can do search a larger table, but get a **significantly** smaller array to work with?

Comment: you are probably running out of memory because `$blogs = $wpdb->get_results(` is fetching all 1400 rows into memory. Thats a lot of data. Instead, you should use a function that returns a resource handle, or an iterator, that allows you to fetch one row at a time into memory for processing, and then discard that data, freeing up memory. Check out PDO query for more info on paged queries. It seems you are using wordpress, and I'm not sure if the wordpress library comes with a suitable function for doing this.

Comment: @JoeGreen - Yes I'm using WordPress, but unfortunately they deprecated the function that did this and provided no alternatives :(. That's why I'm trying to rig up something myself. I'll certainly look at 'paged' queries, that sounds like something I could use, thanks

Comment: What about using the MSQL engine to do the search: `WHERE blog_name LIKE "%'.$_GET['squery'].'%"` (of course, DO NOT put raw user input directly into a query - use prepared statements or if you must, some sort of real_escape_string function to escape the data)

Comment: blog_name isn't found in this table. for each result, I'm running WordPress's `switch_to_blog($blog_id)` function, hence why this first array has been so big (since I didn't know about paged queries or anything)

Comment: @shortbus I have no idea what your column names are :) change it to what ever column your blog title is stored in...

Answer (score 0):

Try using LIMIT in your SQL statement, so you could get your data by smaller chunks.

Something like:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(id) AS rowCount FROM {$wpdb->blogs}");
$rowCount = $result->rowCount;

for($offset=0; $offset<$rowCount; $offset+=50)
{
    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT blog_id,path FROM {$wpdb->blogs} 
            WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} 
                AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}' 
                AND spam = '0' 
                AND deleted = '0' 
                AND archived = '0' 
                    ORDER BY blog_id
                        LIMIT {$offset},50", ARRAY_A);

    foreach( $blogs as $blog ) : 
        switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );
        if(strpos(strtolower($blog_details->blogname), 
            strtolower($_GET['squery'])) !== false){
            //Show the site's title and link to the site
    }
    endforeach;
}
```

By doing this you're definetly increasing the number of sql queries, but anyways, the overall memory usage will be significantly lower. 50 is less than 1400, yep.

PS: And yeah, for any TEXT search, you should better try Sphinx/Solr/ElasticSearch/etc as MySQL isn't the fastest thing to handle it.

Comment: Hmm, that might actually work for what I need. Is there a way to get it to cycle through automatically?